# Delete files when closing Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When closing the Eclipse IDE, it should delete some files (more precisely: every file in a special folder). How can I realize this?

I need this because I'd like to delete eventually stored SVN credentials.

Comment: You have to develop an eclipse plugin for this.

Comment: I've already noticed this. But I don't have a clue how to start....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IWorkbenchListener` may be a solution.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchListener.html.

You implement your lestiner and register it on the workbench object using the `addWorkbenchListener` method.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbench.html#addWorkbenchListener(org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchListener)

To get started with Eclipse plugin development you can follow this article: http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=370. I'll not go into details in this answer because it will be quite long and you can easily find good resources in addition to one above on the subject. Once your plugin will be created, you'll just have to register your listener in the activation method of the plugin.

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().addWorkbenchListener(new IWorkbenchListener(){

preShutdown(IWorkbench workbench) {
  // delete your files here ....
}
postShutdown(IWorkbench workbench)  {
// Nothing to do
}
});
```

I don't remember the method name, and if it's required if you don't need special behavior at starting time but you should also easily find that online.

Comment: Could you please be more detailed, I've never written an eclipse extension/plugin bevore.